# C# Generic Deserializer by calling static methods

Tags: c#, json, generics

I am deserializing lots of data with the `Newtonsoft Json.NET` library. Performance is high-priority, so all model classes are being manually deserialized with a `JsonReader`. Each model class has its own static constructor method `FromJson` which accepts a `JsonReader` to do the reading.

```
class Example
{

  public Guid? Id { get; private set; }
  public DateTime? Date { get; private set; }
  public decimal? Amount { get; private set; }

  public static Example FromJson(JsonReader reader)
  {
    var example = new Example();

    reader.SkipToStartObject(); // Extension method, skips to first JsonToken.StartObject
    while(reader.Read() && reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName)
    {
      var propertyName = reader.Value.ToString();

      switch(propertyName)
      {
        case "id":
          example.Id = reader.ReadAsGuid(); // Extension method
          break;
        case "date":
          example.Date = reader.ReadAsDateTime();
          break;
        case "amount":
          example.Amount = reader.ReadAsDecimal();
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }

    return example;
  }
}
```

I would like to somehow interface this class so that I can write a generic deserializer that takes that interface and automatically calls the `FromJson()` method. Ideally, I would be able to cleanly deserialize a `WebResponse` in a manner like so.

```
var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
var stream = response.GetResponseStream();

return GenericJsonDeserializer.Deserialize<Example>(stream);
```

The `GenericJsonDeserializer` would constrain the allowed types to only those with the interface, set up a `JsonReader` from the stream, deserialize with the `FromJson` method, and return the object.

One problem is that C# interfaces don't allow required constructors, nor do they allow static methods. Thus, I cannot constrain `GenericJsonSerializer`.

This problem is solvable with reflection, but that brings about a new problem. Performance is critical, and I cannot afford to use reflection in this case. Creating a new instance inside of the generic method would either:

- Require the use of `Activator` if the deserialization code was handled in a regular constructor, or
- Require reflection to obtain the static `FromJson` function and invoke it, which is probably even slower.

In either case, compiling `DynamicMethod`s by emitting IL would be a best bet (and probably offer the best performance), but I would like to avoid that scenario if possible.

Is there any other way I can constrain a generic method to require either a static constructor or a constructor overload that accepts a `JsonReader` for deserialization?

Comment: It seems a little like you are re-inventing the wheel here. Are you really having performance issues using Newtonsoft's default JSON deserialization?

Comment: Performance issues? Not necessarily. My job is to optimize what we already have. Using manual deserialization has cut our benchmark times down by 2-5x.

That's not the issue here though. The issue is being able to encapsulate the deserialization into one call so that creation of a `JsonReader` or other utilities are all done behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using here the type 'Example':

```
GenericJsonDeserializer.Deserialize<Example>(stream);
```

You can just use:

```
Example.FromJson
```

Beacause you need to know the type anyway.

Just make a version that accepts Stream and JsonReader or whatever.
You can share the logic for creating JsonReader by some other static class if you need to.

There is also another approach. You can move / extract your FromJson method to  another class / interface:

```
interface IMyJsonDeserializer
{
    void FromJson(Stream stream, out ExampleClassA result);
    void FromJson(Stream stream, out ExampleClassB result);
}

class MyJsonDeserializer : IMyJsonDeserializer
{
    public void FromJson(Stream stream, out ExampleClassA result)
    {
        // code to deserialize
    }

    public void FromJson(Stream stream, out ExampleClassB result)
    {
        // code to deserialize
    }

    // .. more methods
}
```

Usage:

```
var deserializer = new MyJsonDeserializer(); // you can create it just once somewhere

ExampleClassA a;
deserializer.FromJson(stream, out a);

ExampleClassB b;
deserializer.FromJson(stream, out b);
```

If you have a lot of classes you can do some interface segregation and inheritance. You can now share your logic for creating JsonReader from Stream using OOP methods.

If you do care about perfrormance you can take a look at [Utf8Json](https://github.com/neuecc/Utf8Json). It is proved to be faster than Newtonsoft.Json

Answer (score 1):

Instead of constraining the ctor, you can constrain to an initialize method:

> the self referencing constraint is not really necessary

```
public interface IDeserializable<T> where T : IDeserializable<T>, new()
{
    T FromJson(JsonReader reader);
}
```

Then modify `Example` to implement that interface:

```
public class Example : IDeserializable<Example>
{
    //...

    public Example FromJson(JsonReader reader)
    {
        // populate the object with json...
        // you can create complex object like this:
        // this.Example2 = new Example2().FromJson(reader);

        return this;
    }
}
```

Finally, define the `Deserialize` method as such:

```
public static class GenericJsonSerializer
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(Stream steam) where T :  IDeserializable<T>, new()
    {
        using (var reader = ...)
        {
            var result = new T();
            result.FromJson(reader);

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```